# C++/CLI - Convert System::Object to ContextMenuStrip

Tags: c++-cli

I'm working on a piece of legacy code & I'm trying to update some of the interface. I'm not proficient in C++/CLI and the documentation for C++/CLI is sparse at best. I do my best to convert C# documentation to C++/CLI but it doesn't always work.

I want to convert a System::Object to a ContextMenuStrip.

A sample code is:

```
System::Void Form1::unzoomToolStripMenuItem_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e)
{

    System::Windows::Forms::ContextMenuStrip ^menu = sender;
    //a value of type "System::Object ^" cannot be used to initialize and entity of type "System::Windows::Forms::ContextMenuStrip ^"

    //Other code here
}
```

How is this done in C++/CLI?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1bh3t52k.aspx

Comment: You may try the following `auto menu = (System::Windows::Forms::ContextMenuStrip ^)sender;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the link posted by Hans Passant:

> A downcast is a cast from a base class to a class that's derived from the base class. A downcast is safe only if the object that's addressed at runtime is actually addressing a derived class object. Unlike static_cast, safe_cast performs a dynamic check and throws InvalidCastException if the conversion fails.

So you should use:

```
Windows::Forms::ContextMenuStrip ^menu = safe_cast<Windows::Forms::ContextMenuStrip^>(sender);
```